# How to delete all Stripe plans at once via the Stripe API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Is there a way to delete **all** Stripe plans *at once* via the Stripe API?

According to [their API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#delete_plan) you have to select each plan individually in order to delete it:

```
plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve({PLAN_ID})
plan.delete
```

This is not ideal for me, though, as I will have to delete all my plans on a regular basis. Plus I found that looping through all plans and then deleting them individually is also error prone since it will not always find all plans.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to delete all the plans at once. You need to delete each individually, although that only requires a few lines of code to pull off.

Also, to be clear, deleting a plan will not delete the subscriptions to that plan. This can be confusing, so I'd recommend never deleting plans or deleting the subscriptions to that plan first.

Best,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.